# How can I query all the 'RUNNING' JOBS on SQL-Server with their details?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

How query all the 'RUNNING' (enabled) JOBS on SQL-Server with their details (especially the start-time, frequency) via T-SQL script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
use msdb
select distinct a.name JOBNAME, isnull(DESCRIPTION,'No description available') DESCRIPTION,c.Name Category, 
isnull (b.database_name,'None') DATABASE_NAME, isnull(f.name, 'None') Job_Owner,
case when d.name is null then 'No Schedule' else d.name end Schedule,
isnull (case d.freq_type
when '1 ' then 'Once'
when '4' then 'Daily'
when '8' then 'Weekly'
when '16' then 'Monthly'
when '32' then 'Monthly relative'
when '64' then 'When SQL Server Agent starts' end, 'None') as Frequency,
isnull (case d.freq_interval
when '1' then 'None'
when '2' then 'Monday'
when '4' then 'Tuesday'
when '8' then 'Wednesday'
when '16' then 'Thursday'
when '32' then 'Friday'
when '64' then 'Saturday'
end,'None') as DAY,
case when active_start_time < 120000 then
isnull(left(convert(varchar,convert(decimal,D.Active_start_time)/10000),4) + ' AM','None') else
isnull(left(convert(varchar,convert(decimal,D.Active_start_time)/10000-12),4) + ' PM','None') END
JOB_start_time,
isnull (convert (varchar,d.Date_Created), 'None') Created_Date 
from sysjobs a
Inner join sysjobsteps b on
a.job_id = b.job_id
left outer join syscategories c on a.category_id = c.category_id
left outer join master.dbo.syslogins f on a.Owner_sid = f.sid
left outer join sysjobschedules e on e.job_id = a.job_id
left outer join sysschedules d on e.schedule_id = d.schedule_id
where a.enabled = 1
order by a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this query on your `sql-server`

```
   SELECT *
   FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS JobStep
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS Job ON JobStep.job_id = Job.job_id
   WHERE enabled=1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you start FROM sysjobsteps instead of sysjobs? (Just noticed as KuldipMCA's query starts FROM Sysjobs)

Comment: @pencilCake: It doesn't matter as per my knowledge :)

Comment: @pencilCake: did you got the expected result?